# How to make Discord.py music bot automatically play next song in queue

Tags: python, discord, audio-player

After song finishes, song is popped from the playlist queue, but does not continue playing the next song in queue. So the queue command only shows the song sitting in there. How should I change this to run the next song?

````
playlist = []

@client.command(name='play', help='Plays music')
async def play(ctx):
    voice = ctx.message.guild.voice_client

    def is_connected():  # Tests if bot is connected to voice channel
        voice_client = discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        return voice_client and voice_client.is_connected()

    url = ctx.message.content.lstrip('?play')
    playlist.append(url.lstrip(' '))

    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        playlist.pop(0)
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    if is_connected():
        if voice.is_playing():  # url already added to the playlist, downloads each index
            index = len(playlist)-1
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(playlist[index], loop=client.loop)
            await ctx.send('**Added:** {} to queue'.format(player.title))
            playlist[index] = player.title
        else:
            server = ctx.message.guild
            voice_channel = server.voice_client
            async with ctx.typing():
                player = await YTDLSource.from_url(playlist[0], loop=client.loop)
                voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else ctx.send('hi'))
                print(player.title)
            await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
            playlist[0] = player.title
            playlist.pop(0)
    else:
        await channel.connect()
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(playlist[0], loop=client.loop)
            voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
            print(player.title)
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
        playlist[0] = player.title```
````

Answer (score 1):

````
        await channel.connect()
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(playlist[0], loop=client.loop)
            voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(after_play(ctx), client.loop))
            print(player.title)
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
        playlist[0] = player.title


async def after_play(ctx):
    playlist.pop(0)
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(playlist[0], loop=client.loop)
    voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(after_play(ctx), client.loop))
    print(player.title)```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Music related things you have to set up more than things like commands (play, skip, disconnect, etc.).
Kindly look at examples on Music bots and stuff.
I have one but it's old but the logic is what you need. https://github.com/Gaming-Rowdies/cs-music/